# Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk' Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true)

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

working on flutter mobile application. I am having compilation issue in my code.
Here is the screenshot of error it shows. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8fHt.png)

Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're using the getflutter plugin with a recent version of Flutter, probably a 2.0.X and/or in a project where the null-safety is activated.

Since the getflutter plugin has been discontinued, I strongly advise you to replace this plugin in your app with the new version, [getwidget](https://pub.dev/packages/getwidget).

Otherwise, you'll have to downgrade the Flutter version you are using, and probably disable the null safety. I'd need more informations to confirm this hypothesis though.